# AJAX form executing only once (for first input)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I looped output of sql select rows via `while` loop. Each rows have own form. Only first form is working. Others forms are just refreshing page withour any results. On form submit 
via AJAX update.php function is executed. Its only working at first input field and don't know how to trigger others.

**PHP**

```
echo " <div class=\"col-6 flex-vcenter-items fs-1\">
    <form id='form".$row["id"]."' action='' method='POST'>
         <input id='id' name='potnik' value='".$row["id"]."' type='hidden' /> 
         <input id='cas' class=\"form-control cas".$row["id"]." fancy-border\" type=\"text\" name=\"posodobljeni_cas\"/>
         <input class='btn btn-outline-primary' id='submit' type='submit' value='Nastavi uro'>
     <label id=\"info\"></label>
 </form>
</div>";
```

**JS**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
//Async update
    $(function () {
        let idrow = $("#id").val();
        $('#form'+idrow).on('submit', function (e) {

            let updaterow = "update.php?id=";
            console.log(updaterow + idrow);
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: updaterow + idrow,
                data: $('#form'+idrow).serialize(),
                success: function () {
                    console.log('ura posodobljena');
                    //Koda za vstavljanje
                    console.log("Prejšnji čas",$("#id-ura"+idrow).text());
                    $("#id-ura"+idrow).replaceWith( $(".cas"+idrow).val() );
                    console.log("Novi čas",$(".cas"+idrow).val());
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: 1. `let idrow = $("#id").val();` will always give you first form .2. Instead of `id's` use `class` and make your code easy and fine

Comment: @AlivetoDie let idrow = $("#id").val(); is used only as combining variable. I use it only to combine update.php?id= + id number

Comment: why don't you use data-id for idrow ?

Comment: @AlivetoDie I changed `let idrow = $("#id").val();` to `let idrow = $(".potnikid").val()`, also added `potnikid` class where was ` #id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic HTML rule is each element has  `unique` id, since you are creating `forms` in loop i will use `classes` instead of `id's`

```
echo " <div class=\"col-6 flex-vcenter-items fs-1\">
    <form class='form' data-id='".$row["id"]."' action='' method='POST'>
         <input  name='potnik' value='".$row["id"]."' type='hidden' /> 
         <input  class=\"form-control cas".$row["id"]." fancy-border\" type=\"text\" name=\"posodobljeni_cas\"/>
         <input class='btn btn-outline-primary' type='submit' value='Nastavi uro'>
        <label class=\"info\"></label>
    </form>
</div>";
```

Now i will change jQuery code according to the class:-

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=submit]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var obj = $(this);
        let idrow = obj.closest("form").data('id'); // i have used data-id in forms
        let updaterow = "update.php?id=";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: updaterow + idrow,
            data: obj.closest("form").serialize(),
            success: function () {
                //change these code also based on classes
                console.log('ura posodobljena');
                console.log("Prejšnji čas",$("#id-ura"+idrow).text());
                $("#id-ura"+idrow).replaceWith( $(".cas"+idrow).val() );
                console.log("Novi čas",$(".cas"+idrow).val());
            }
        });
    });
});
```